# Get div nth-child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get the nth-child of a div via jquery, so I can display different contents on the same screen, kinda like tabs would, but the selector just won't work. I have the following code to deal with.

This is the code for the tabs:

```js
$("li, .tablink").click(function() {

  var $this = $("li, .tablink")

  if ($this.is(':nth-child(1)')) {
    alert("1");
  } else {
    alert("2");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabsContent">
  <ul>
    <li class="tabLink active">tab1</li>
    <li class="tabLink">tab2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content1">
  first content of the page
</div>
<div class="content2">
  second content of the page
</div>
<div class="content3">
  third content of the page
</div>
```

All I want is to have a jquery that says "Whenever I click on the first tab, I'll display the first content of that page and so on"

Ps: I can't do it just with CSS because this is a large project, and the I have to use the same HTML file that contains the tabs in every page of the project - and of course, each page have its own sets of tabs and content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var $this = $("li, .tablink")` is incorrect.  You should just be using `this` passed to a jQuery object like so: `$(this)`.

```js
$("li, .tablink").click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':nth-child(1)')) {
            alert("1");
        } else {
            alert("2");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabsContent">
  <ul>
    <li class="tabLink active">tab1</li>
    <li class="tabLink">tab2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

    <div class="content1">
      first content of the page
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      second content of the page
    </div>
<div class="content3">
      third content of the page
    </div>
```

But if I understand what you're trying to do, you're better off just getting the index:

```js
$("li, .tablink").click(function(){
        alert($(this).index() + 1);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabsContent">
  <ul>
    <li class="tabLink active">tab1</li>
    <li class="tabLink">tab2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

    <div class="content1">
      first content of the page
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      second content of the page
    </div>
<div class="content3">
      third content of the page
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the tabs and content ordering is the same you can use indexing.

Also assumes common class on all content

```js
$("li.tabLink").click(function() {
  // $(this).index() gets index of current <li> within it's siblings
  // eq() returns content with same index
  $('.content').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

```css
.content{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabsContent">
  <ul>
    <li class="tabLink active">tab1</li>
    <li class="tabLink">tab2</li>
    <li class="tabLink">tab3</li>
  </ul>
</div>



<div class="content">
  first content of the page
</div>
<div class="content">
  second content of the page
</div>
<div class="content">
  third content of the page
</div>
```